# Unable to access link from India in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, automation, proxy, vpn

I am trying to access a website using automation in python but that will work only from India. But I am unable to do so.

The current code with the website link is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

r = driver.get("https://visa.vfsglobal.com/ind/en/pol/")

time.sleep(15)
```

Although i have used selenium for automation but it is not necessary. Any other alternative library or anything will work too. Help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could doing that without any problems.
I'm not from India.
This is my code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)

url = "https://visa.vfsglobal.com/ind/en/pol/"
driver.get(url)
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: Okay so the problem is that after clicking Book Now twice it gives me access denied. the actual link is https://row2.vfsglobal.com/GAPolandAppt/Account/RegisteredLogin?q=shSA0YnE4pLF9Xzwon/x/ASnHZRMROGDyz5YljrTPrmbws9m3YKnjDXuh/15KyMksdtUgr/FOny2C0bQ3U4uiw==
I am from Pakistan so it wont work here. I just want to know how to use the vpn or proxy so that if i simply open Google it shows Google India and not any other

Comment: This is not what you wrote in the question...

Comment: Okay so can tell me now about this new thing?

Comment: I never used selenium with vpn. I'm sorry.

Comment: Okay no issues.